# Broadcast listeners aren't set before the broadcast event

Tags: angularjs, events, broadcast

Could anyone give me some tips on how to handle the situation when broadcast listeners aren't set before the broadcast event?

I've seen some solutions with $timeout, but they don't feel OK. Thanks!

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('ParentCtrl',
  function ParentCtrl ($scope) {
    this.data = 'parent';
    $scope.$broadcast('parent', 'Some data'); // event is sent before any listeners are set
});

app.controller('ChildCtrl',
  function SiblingOneCtrl ($scope) {  
    this.data = 'child';
    $scope.$on('parent', function (event, data) {
      document.write(data); // never activates
    });
});
```

Working example:
http://codepen.io/AndriusRimkus/pen/zqMONm

Answer (score 1):

In your case, you will always try to broadcast before any listener will be subscribed.

That's because you `ParentCtrl` will always initialized **before** `ChildCtrl`.
Try to watch on you controllers like a constructors.

If you what to broadcast something to you child controllers then you need to have some events (like, clicks) to start broadcasting manually, but not from controller directly.